# how to get hex or decimal equivilant of bootstrap entity

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular2-template

I'm uing angular2 and it does not like using a entity reference like

`<span class="badge">&check;</span>`

How do I determine or find the hex or decimal equivalent of `&check;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hex: &#x2713;
dec: &#10003;
```

See

- http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2713/index.htm

And for future reference and search:

- http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm